# Printing multiple items onto one line

Tags: python, printing

I have been trying to make a program that encrypts any message that you enter into it. At the moment, each number (1 for each character of the original message) is printed in reverse order on a separate line for each number. I would like it if the numbers were printed onto the same line if possible.

This is my code so far:

```
whinger = 0F
bewds = raw_input ('Please enter the message that you wish to encrypt: ')
dooblew = list(bewds)
wetler = len(dooblew)FF
dooblew.reverse();
while whinger < wetler:
    print ord(dooblew[whinger])
    whinger += 1
```

The random variable names are to make sure that they are unlikely to be inputted by the user.

Comment: It may be helpful to include the language you're using (as a tag).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sys.stdout.write(str(ord(dooblew[whinger]))` instead of the `print` statement (you'll have to `import` the `sys` module of course).

Alternatively, you could add a comma after the `print` statement. This will get rid of the newline, but still separate each value with a space.

Aside: The random variable names are kind of pointless. They make the code hard to read and it wouldn't make any difference if the user enters one of your variable names.

Answer (score 0):

On python 2, you can just use a comma at the end of print to indicate that print won't put a newline by default. SO your syntax in that case would be

```
whinger = 0
bewds = raw_input ('Please enter the message that you wish to encrypt: ')
dooblew = list(bewds)
wetler = len(dooblew)
dooblew.reverse();
while whinger < wetler:
   print ord(dooblew[whinger]),
   whinger += 1
```

In case of Python 3, the same could be achieved by

```
whinger = 0
bewds = raw_input ('Please enter the message that you wish to encrypt: ')
dooblew = list(bewds)
wetler = len(dooblew)
dooblew.reverse();
while whinger < wetler:
   print(ord(dooblew[whinger]), end='')
   whinger += 1
```